# Request for an existing file causes 404 error

Tags: htaccess, apache, 404, cache

A customer cannot access a file that I put online for him, or the folder that it is in.

**Requests for both the folder (/bastide) and the file (/bastide/coupon%20d'engagement.pdf) return 404 errors.**

I can visit both myself without any problems. The site is hosted on a Linode server in Frankfurt.

The site is a simple page with some graphic design projects for a client at [pub.biotinel.fr](http://pub.biotinel.fr)

My .htaccess contains:

```
options +indexes

indexoptions +fancyindexing
indexoptions +xhtml
indexoptions +suppresshtmlpreamble
indexoptions +scanhtmltitles
indexoptions +descriptionwidth=300
indexoptions +namewidth=100
indexoptions +htmltable
serversignature off

directoryindex aucun.htm
errordocument 404 /404.htm
```

**The problem is that some files that I added on May 18th (six days ago) are still not visible to the customer -- either on his computer or on his phone.**

Specifically the folder **/bastide** is not showing up.

I have tried renaming various elements in the directory with the client on the phone. I see the changes in real time but the client does not.

Could it be that his DNS servers (Orange, in France) are not updating often enough?

Comment: DNS only ties a domain name to an IP address - this would have nothing to do with your issue if your customer can get ***TO*** the site. Have you had your customer clear their browser cache?? As well, it may be important to know what browsers you and your customer are using. It is possible that your customers ISP or company are using a cache. Keep this in mind and investigate.

Comment: I will ask him to clear the cache. The problem was the same on a MB Pro and on an iPhone, both through the same wifi connection. I will also ask him to try to connect with 3G to see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely caching issue.

Ask your customer to directly visit http://pub.biotinel.fr/bastide/ and check if he can see the content of the folder.

Also, you may ask your customer to visit http://pub.biotinel.fr/?v=1 - this will most likely fetch the page again and he should see bastide folder.

Comment: The customer can not go to /bastide (404). The problem is not that he's getting a bad version, it's 404 errors.

Comment: So if it's caching, it's caching the whole site, not just a single page.

Comment: In that case, it's something else. Do you have some sort of firewall in your server? I think somehow his IP is getting blocked. That can be a possible reason. If yes (for firewall), whitelist his IP address or disable the firewall to check.